# Using HttpClient request without caching URL

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have a small e-commerce written using Angular 5 framework. It works as it should do overall but there's a small issue though. It should show other prices for logged in users. This Angular app is caching API urls and this means that I don't have an ability to get a product with its new price as Angular doesn't make a new call, it's just taking data from its cache.

The question is how do I remove all the cached urls? I guess it's quite possible to add some additional parameter to URL addresses every time. But I'm sure there should be the other way.

Comment: Remove the part in wich you cached the result. (possibly you have an interceptor) Angular don't cached anything by defect

Comment: The caching is done by the browser. You have two possibilities: 1. set the no-cache header on the server side. 2. Add a url parameter containing a timestamp to make the url unique.

Comment: Thanks guys!
There are no interceptors in the app, I thought it's Angular does this caching.
OK, I'll add a timestamp parameter to URLs then.